# ConcurrentModificationException but I am not modifying the Collection I am iterating

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am iterating over a list of Message objects with the attempt to get all conversations, where conversation means that a subsequent message was sent within 20 Minutes after the previous message.

The first iteration works fine, and in the second one I am getting a **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**
Even though I am not modifying the Message List I am iterating. See code below.

```
public List<Chat> getAllConversations(int allowedMinutes) {
    List<Chat> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Chat currentConvo = new Chat();
    List<Message> ml = this.getMessageList();
    for (Message m : ml) {
        if (currentConvo.getMessageList().isEmpty() || m.getDateTime().until(currentConvo.getMessageList().get(currentConvo.getMessageList().size() - 1).getDateTime(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES) <= allowedMinutes) {
            currentConvo.addMessage(m);
            continue;
        }
        if (currentConvo.getAllParticipants().size() > 1) {
            // only if more than one participant is involved it is a conversation
            result.add(currentConvo);
        }
        // not more than one person involved and also last message is too long ago -> discard the current conversation
        currentConvo = new Chat();
        currentConvo.addMessage(m);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the Error Message:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chatstats, PID: 22185
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at com.example.chatstats.Chat.getAllConversations(Chat.java:188)
    at com.example.chatstats.MainActivity.onClickShowResults(MainActivity.java:169)
    at com.example.chatstats.MainActivity$9.onClick(MainActivity.java:152)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 14.815ms for cause HeapTrim
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8622', transport: 
'socket'
```

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: What is line `188` from the stack trace? That's where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: You didn't show other parts of code and there's no any immutablility at the moment. The error will occur, if you'd try to modify during loop as well. Consider working with immutable list (CopyOnWriteArrayList), which is costy or find a way not to update list during loop.

Comment: *Theory:* Your `Chat` class stores the messages in a **`static`** field, so even though your code uses 2 different `Chat` objects, there is only one list, which means that `currentConvo.addMessage(m);` ***modifies*** the list returned by `this.getMessageList();`, given that `this` is a `Chat` object (see stacktrace). --- That is of course just a guess, since you haven't shared the *relevant* code, but it is an educated guess, since `currentConvo = new Chat(); currentConvo.addMessage(m);` would otherwise make no sense at all, adding to a new chat and then throwing the object away.

Answer (score 2):

But you are; the exception is not lying to you. It is possible another thread is doing it; it is more likely one of the lines in your forloop is causing a change. For example, perhaps the `addMessage` command figures out which Chat the message is already a part of, and removes it from there – i.e. from you, changing the list.

EDIT: As Andreas has commented, another plausible explanation is that you've accidentally made the `messageList` field `static`. In that case, all the different chat objects share a single list, and thus, adding a message to a newly created Chat object is still adding it to the single global list. Solution if this is the case: Make it non-static.

Comment: More likely, the `messageList` field of class `Chat` is `static`. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516075/concurrentmodificationexception-but-i-am-not-modifying-the-collection-i-am-itera#comment107060238_60516075).

Comment: Oh, yeah - that's a very plausible explanation.